# How to install i2c.dev on old macbook

Tags: installation, arduino, arduino-uno

I need to install the i2c.dev library for a project on an arduino uno, but I am having problems when trying to install it. I searched it up online, and I downloaded a zip file of the package, unziped it, but I can't get it to install. From reading online, I think I need to add the I2C.dev folder into my library, so I go Sketch - Include Library - Add .ZIP Library. However, I'm not able to add the I2C.dev folder (in the Arduino Folder), the open button doesn't work. Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[Selecting I2C.dev folder (no open button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt1t6.png)

This is what happens when I just select the zip file itself (i2cdevlibmaster.zip):

[Error Mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGIwl.png)

I am using a mac which is on high sierra. Does anybody know what my problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionend by creator on github,

> Move or copy the relevant core and device drivers into your project tree or library subfolder
> (For Arduino, this means the /Arduino/I2Cdev and /Arduino/MPU6050 folders, for example)

so after unzipping i2cdevlib-master.zip, copy all subFolders from
\i2cdevlib-master\Arduino
to your arduino libraries folder.

you can then open sketch in IDE files/examples like 'MPU6050'

code start with

```
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"
```

and it compile without error.

don't use

```
#include <I2Cdev>
```

it fail to compile.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't aware I had to actually copy the folders into the library. It worked great.